# Dropbox won't sync on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sync, dropbox

I have tried every solution I can find by googling, so I'm resorting to posting a question. If this has been solved, please point me to the solution because I can't find it.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a four-year-old Dell Inspiron 2-in-1 series. I installed Dropbox, and initially it worked. It downloaded all my files from my Dropbox account onto my computer. But then, I closed my laptop, reopened it some time later, and now Dropbox won't sync at all. It says "syncing" in the notification tray, but it doesn't give a time estimate or anything, and it never stops saying "syncing." It doesn't actually sync any files either.

I have restarted the application, rebooted my pc, done advanced reinstalls, completely removed all dropbox files and tried it again, and nothing works. Please help. I'm using dropbox for school, and now that COVID-19 is running rampant, we are doing distance learning, so I have to use my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have fixed it! Leaving this up in case it helps someone else.

I tried everything, but in the end all I did to solve it was run

```
dropbox start
```

And then entered the command it told me to. I'm attaching screen shots of my terminal to show what happened.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhLqp.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BksSl.png)

Comment: I've been driving myself crazy and have gone through three customer service people - this worked! 
To expand in case those links die - start with dropbox off. Then run `dropbox start` You'll get a long echo statement, copy and paste the command. After that's successful, quit dropbox, type `dropbox start` again.